# Add a click event to a dynamic list in a dynamic collapsible div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add a collapsible div with a list to an ui-block and I want click events for the li elements.
I have an ui-grid like this:

```
<div class="ui-block-b" id="right">
    <h3>Test</h3>
</div>
```

Then I use this Javascript code to add a collapsible div with a list in it to the grid.

```
var div = '<div data-role="collapsible"><h3>Handy</h3></div>';
var list = '<ul class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow" data-inset="true" data-role="listview"</ul>';
var li = '<li>Samsung</li>';
list = $(list).append(li);
li = '<li>Apple</li>';
list = $(list).append(li);
$(list).appendTo(div).parent().appendTo('#right').end().trigger("create");
$('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible();
```

This works but when I try to add an click event to the li with this code nothing happens / the event don't "fire".

```
$("#right").children("div").on("click", "ul li", function() {
    alert("Right");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("#right").on("click", "div ul li", function() {
    alert("Right");
});
```

---

or

```
$("#right").on("click", "li", function() {
    alert("Right");
});
```

---

i hope you are wrapping you code in [DOM ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

---

Problem with your code you are trying to select children `div` of `$("#right")` which is not present in DOM at the time you want to select it ,That's why your code not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#right").off("click").on("click", "div ul li", function() {
    alert("Right");
});

or

$("#right").off("click").on("click", "li", function() {
    alert("Right");
});
```